# relative URI in sidebar with subfolders

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

I have designed a website with subfolders and a sidebar with the navigation menu, however when I enter a page in a subfolder, all the links refers to that current folder instead of the root, using tilde doesnt resolve the issue, If for example i type something like this:

```
<a href="~/editor.aspx">
```

it will not lookup the tilde ad root folder but will look for it in the path and will fail, so If im in the subfolder "articles" and on the page "resume.aspx" it will try to lookup for:

```
http://www.website.../articles/~/editor.aspx
```

How can I correctly use root reference in my `<a>` tag without using `Server.MapPath` on all my sidebar (Masterpage) links?

**edit**: what happens when your current folder will be set to "articles" and you click on "/register.aspx"? wont it look for the page under "articles" folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A root-relative URL starts with a `/` character.So, just `<a href="/editor.aspx">` will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the / without the ~

Thanks
Flávio

Comment: Please don't add a signature to answers.  It's just noise.